# Whenever I render, it doesn't show the texture

Tags: rendering, texturing

I make GFX on a game called Roblox, and today I was making one but when I rendered it, the render didn't have the texture on it. It still has the texture on it in 3D View though.[image] Please help because I cannot find a solution anywhere online and I have tried most things and it still doesn't have the texture on in the render, even though it does it 3D View.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the blend file?

Comment: I don't know how to sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about it, just go to this url https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ , drag and drop your file and then paste this question's url below

Comment: Okay I did. You can find it at the end of my question.

Comment: You forgot the texture images, you can pack them in the blend by going to File > External Data > Automatically pack into .blend

Comment: It's still not showing the texture even after I do what you said for me to do.

Comment: Ho no ,that's for me to take a look to the mesh with the images, the file that you upload a few minutes ago did not have the texture images. I did try with a random image and it worked. So I'll like to take a look with your textures to find out wath's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your texture is an image file this should work.

Change it from Blender Render to Cycles Render. [image]Go into edit mode(tab-key) and unwrap it(u-key). [image]Go into the node editor[image]. In the node editor bring up the node add menu (shift + a), and select image texture. Assign your image/texture to the image texture box[image]. Attach the yellow node from the texture image box to the diffuse box.[image]. This should work.

Comment: Before visiting the Node Editor panel, is it necessary to go to Properties panel -> Material and click Use Nodes?

Comment: It is necessary to enable nodes. Like you suggested, you can do that in the material panel, but you can also do it when you open the nodes editor. There should be a check box at the bottom of the editor that you can click to enable it.